Debian Testing - Gnome 47 - Nautilus doesn't start anymore. Why?
I am using Debian Testing. After an update, Nautilus doesn't start anymore.
Launching it from terminal gives this:
$ nautilus
** Message: 16:38:50.596: Connecting to org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Files
MESA-INTEL: warning: ../src/intel/vulkan/anv_formats.c:763: FINISHME: support YUV colorspace with DRM format modifiers
MESA-INTEL: warning: ../src/intel/vulkan/anv_formats.c:794: FINISHME: support more multi-planar formats with DRM modifiers

(org.gnome.Nautilus:85373): Gdk-WARNING **: 16:38:51.083: The program 'org.gnome.Nautilus' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)'.
  (Details: serial 1021 error_code 8 request_code 149 (unknown) minor_code 4)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the GDK_SYNCHRONIZE environment
   variable to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)

Version:
$ apt-cache policy nautilus
nautilus:
  Installed: 47.0-1
  Candidate:  47.0-1
  Version Table:
 *** 47.0-1 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian testing/main amd64 Packages

What can I do?

It sounds like you should report the bug to Debian (reportbug nautilus). Have you tried downgrading Nautilus to the previous version?

I downgraded Nautilus to version 43.2-1 and now it can be launched.

Ah great. If that works for you, could you please post an answer explaining how/what you did so the question can be marked as answered?

Downgrading Nautilus as terdon suggested worked for me:
First check which versions of Nautilus are available:
apt policy nautilus

Pin packages:
sudo nano /etc/apt/preferences.d/nautilus

Add the following lines to pin the older versions of the dependent packages as well:
Package: nautilus
Pin: version 43.2-1
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: libnautilus-extension4
Pin: version 43.2-1
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: nautilus-data
Pin: version 43.2-1
Pin-Priority: 1001

Update packages:
sudo apt update

Downgrade all relevant packages:
sudo apt install nautilus=43.2-1 libnautilus-extension4=43.2-1 nautilus-data=43.2-1

Prevent future upgrades (optional):
sudo apt-mark hold nautilus libnautilus-extension4 nautilus-data


It seems to be related by a bug introduced in GTK version of GNOME 47. As a temporal workaround, try by setting the GSK_RENDERER environment variable.
Just for Nautilus:
sudo echo "GSK_RENDERER=cairo /usr/bin/nautilus \$@" > /usr/local/bin/nautilus
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/nautilus

Globally:
sudo echo "GSK_RENDERER=cairo" > /etc/environment.d/99gsk-wa.conf
sudo systemctl restart gdm

Links:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/4165
https://forum.endeavouros.com/t/nautilus-freezes-and-crashes-on-launch-after-gnome-47-update/60669

